# How to add cmd command execution to right click menu on Windows?

Tags: windows, registry

I’m trying to add a menu button when I right click a file and the button will let me execute a command. To be more specific, I’m trying to right click a apk file, and the I can execute a “adb install” command of the selected file. I did some search and found out to add a menu item we need to modify the registry. But I’m not sure how to execute a command and moreover, how can I get the current selected file in right click?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to get the selected file, the entry you put into the registry will allow parameter substitution to put the file path into the command.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for your comment! but the apk file might be different in different locations. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: "File path" means both the file name and location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [Verbs and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs) on MSDN.

If you don't need it to be the default command, adding it under SystemFileAssociations is a good idea and works on Windows XP and later.

A minimal .reg file might look like this:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.apk\shell\AdbInstall]
@="ADB Install"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.apk\shell\AdbInstall\command]
@="\"C:\\path\\to\\androidsdk\\adb.exe\" install \"%1\""
```

%1 is replaced with the full path of the file you right-click on.

Comment: "This file does not have an app associated with it to perform this action..." this message is thrown as an error

Comment: @Anup Did you right click the .apk? Did you change the path to adb.exe so it is correct?

Comment: actually, i was missing adb in the system path, after adding it and running adb install, this is what I see,
`adb.exe: filename doesn't end .apk or .apex: "C:\test.apk"`

Comment: @Anup Maybe it does not like the quotes?